# How to add a webpart to a listview in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have to add a "Content Editor" web part to a list view. The "Content Editor" is required to implement some java script and a html textbox.

The problem is that after adding the web part to the list view the dropdown to switch your current view gets lost. It doesnt matter where you add the web part or if you try it with the designer or IE.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? Or is there another way to implement java script into a listview without adding a new web part?

This is the dropdown I mean:

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known issue with SharePoint 2010.

You can modify the page using SharePoint Designer to put it back.

http://vintentou.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/missing-dropdown-menu-for-choosing-of-views/

My company has also produced a free add-on that will do this for a whole site.

http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/free-stuff/view-rescue